# Azure App Services with Docker Compose and django

Tags: docker, django-rest-framework, docker-compose, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have a Django web application and am building the docker into an Azure Container Registry from an Azure Repo and want to host it with an App - Service
Now I have problems with Docker Compose. Do you have a solution?

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis:
    image: "asdf.azurecr.io/backend/redis"
  web:
    image: "asdf.azurecr.io/image"
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - redis
  celery:
    build: .
    command: sh -c "wait-for redis:6379 && wait-for web:8000 -- celery -A asdf worker -l info"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    depends_on:
      - web
      - redis
```

How I should configure the yml so that the celery docker is also built? or where else are the mistakes? The app fails on startup

Comment: Have you had any luck with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In your celery folder you need to have a Dockerfile to build the image and you just need to invoke it at the build commmand. we don't need the command option because we have the depends_on.